# How to use filter to disable adding a product to wishlist?

Tags: plugins, filters, hooks

I am using a [plugin](https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/ti-woocommerce-wishlist/) on my website that made the following filter available:

> Added filter ‘tinvwl_allow_addtowishlist_single_product’ that helps to
>   show/hide the “Add to Wishlist” button for specific products on a
>   single products page

The filter comes into place here:

```
if ( empty( $this->product ) || ! apply_filters( 'tinvwl_allow_addtowishlist_single_product', true, $this->product ) ) {
    return;
}
```

I would now like to add this filter to a single product page to **disable the "add to wishlist" functionality** in some cases, but

- Where should I hook this filer? Should this be hooked at `woocommerce_before_single_product` as found on https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/ ?
- Which arguments do I need in order to pass the *false* option?
- How to add the filter statement correctly in my `functions.php` file?

My current attempt:

```
function disable_add {
    $allow = false;
    $product = $product->get_id();
    return $allow;
    return $product;
}

add_filter( 'tinvwl_allow_addtowishlist_single_product_summary','disable_add', 15, 2 );
```

Answer (score 1):

I was almost correct in my attempt.

- I forgot to add the arguments in my function definition, which is important of course.
- I took the wrong function name, the `_summary` at the end was not needed.

The correct code is the following:

```
/* DISABLE ADD TO WISHLIST FOR USERS WHO AREN'T ADMIN OR SHOP MANAGER */
/* --- */
function remove_add_button ( $allow, $product ) {
    $allow = false;
    $product = $product->get_id();
    return $allow;
    return $product;
}

$user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( ! in_array( 'administrator', (array) $user->roles ) && ! in_array( 'shop_manager', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
    add_filter( 'tinvwl_allow_addtowishlist_single_product','remove_add_button', 15, 2 );
}
```

As you can see I have also added a condition on the user role, so only admins & shop managers can use the button.